# Java Create a a Randomized ArrayList<Integer> that utilizes another ArrayList's numbers

Tags: java, random, arraylist, foreach

I have been having trouble with this one problem.

I need to write a program that produces random permutations of the numbers 1 to 10.

My strategy to approach this would be to:

To generate a random permutation, you need to fill an ArrayList with the numbers **1 to 10** so that **no** **two** entries of the array have the same contents. I want to avoid calling Random.nextInt(). and instead implement a smarter method by making a **second ArrayList** and filling it with the numbers 1 to 10. Then **picking** one of those at random, **removing** it, and **appending** it to the permutation ArrayList. Repeat ten times.

Here is what I have basically:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
public class P4_Icel_Murad_Permutations
{

public static void main(String[] args){
   ArrayList <Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
   P4_Icel_Murad_Permutations obj = new P4_Icel_Murad_Permutations();
   obj.perma(10,1,10);
}
static java.lang.Object[] perma(int n, int a, int b){
    ArrayList <Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
    ArrayList <Integer> randomized = new ArrayList <Integer> ();  

     randomized.add(new Integer(1));
     randomized.add(new Integer(2));
     randomized.add(new Integer(3));
     randomized.add(new Integer(4));
     randomized.add(new Integer(5));
     randomized.add(new Integer(6));
     randomized.add(new Integer(7));
     randomized.add(new Integer(8));
     randomized.add(new Integer(9));
     randomized.add(new Integer(10));
     for(Integer N: randomized){
         Random r = new Random();
        randomized.remove(r);
        myArrayList.add(N);
    }

}
```

}

my problem is that I am not quite sure how I can take from the other list by removing and adding a number to the myArrayList. I cannot seem to use r since it is a primitive type, and I don't know how to make an object for the random class.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is just shuffle the `ArrayList` using `Collections.shuffle()`.

```
ArrayList <Integer> randomized = new ArrayList <Integer> ();  

 randomized.add(new Integer(1));
 randomized.add(new Integer(2));
 randomized.add(new Integer(3));
 randomized.add(new Integer(4));
 randomized.add(new Integer(5));
 randomized.add(new Integer(6));
 randomized.add(new Integer(7));
 randomized.add(new Integer(8));
 randomized.add(new Integer(9));
 randomized.add(new Integer(10));

Collections.shuffle(randomized);
System.out.println(randomized);
```

This would avoid using a seperated `arrayList` also the logic to get a random number and deleting that particular index. In other words **Optimal**

---

The problem with your code is that the random number produced must be in the range of `0` to `size - 1`, You are not taking care of that.

```
Random rand = new Random();

while(randomized.size() != 0)
{
  int randomNum = rand.nextInt(randomized.size());//produces a number within the range.
  myArrayList.add(randomized.get(randomNum));
  randomized.remove(randomNum);
}
System.out.println("List 1: " + randomized);
System.out.println("List 2: " + myArrayList);
```

Comment: If this is for AP Computer Science or another related course, usually you can't use the shuffle method.

Comment: @UmaKanth That's a great method, but apparently I am supposed to use the method given, so is there a way you could help me with the other method?

Comment: @MuradMuhammedIcel I edited the answer. Have a look at it.

Comment: @UmaKanth So the myList is supposed to be myArrayList from my code right?

Comment: @UmaKanth Also I wanted to ask, how am I supposed to display this code my arranging it by List 1: List 2: etc, using System.out.print

Comment: @MuradMuhammedIcel Yeah, I edited the answer for that too.

Comment: @rb612 yes it's for AP Computer Science

Comment: @UmaKanth I'm actually supposed to have list for only the myArrayList part, so I can't include randomized in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're off to a good start. However, I think a better solution might be this:

At the beginning, make an empty ArrayList that will store the already generated values. Inside a for-loop, generate a random number, check to make sure `indexOf` returns -1 (this means it doesn't exist inside the array), and if it does, append to the array, if not, generate again until it returns -1.

If you're going with your existing approach, you want to generate an integer between 0-9 (you can use Random's `nextInt()` method) to create an index.

So it would look like:

```
for(Integer N: randomized){
         Random r = new Random();
         //insert nextInt generator here, store it in a variable (i'm going to use j)
        myArrayList.add(randomized.remove(j));
    }
```

Comment: so I have to make a for like this?                                                                       for(int i = 0; i < randomized.size(); i++){
            if(randomized.indexOf(r) == -1){
                
            }else{
                randomized.append(r);
            }
                
        }

Comment: @MuradMuhammedIcel well it would be if the indexof is -1 then append, else, regenerate.

Answer (score 0):

Shuffling is a surprisingly hard problem because there are lots of ways to get it wrong, but the wrong ways look a lot like the right ways if you're not paying attention.

The canonical answer to this kind of thing is the [Knuth/Fischer-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which is what `Collections.shuffle()` does. Check out that Wikipedia article: it's quite comprehensive.

When implementing shuffling yourself, make sure you read Jeff Atwood's [The Danger of Naïveté](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/) which explains why just "sorting" by random numbers is **not** a correct shuffle, and check out Eric Lippert's [blog posts on randomness](http://ericlippert.com/tag/randomness/) which also provide a lot of useful background in an easy to understand way.